# Which cars are more comfortable?

Tags: noise, suspension

If you're driving for around 4 hours continuously which types of car would stand out in comfort? For example sedan or suv, or any other type.

Definition of Comfort:

- Less noise
- Ease of getting in and out of vehicle
- Easy to see all around the vehicle without much movement
- Seat provides good support for your back, or adjustable to individuals profile.
- Smoothness of the drive. Eg driving on the bumps on the road would be felt the least.

The list can go on. In general, is there any benefits that the height (size) of the vehicle can have in reducing vibration, hence, improving the comfort?

Comment: This question is very subjective and primarily opinion based. What is comfortable to me, may not be comfortable to you. Because of this, it really is not a suitable question for this site.

Comment: As Paul says, this is a very subjective question. As a rough guide, I'd say the more expensive luxury saloons/sedans are generally the most comfortable, due to the desires of their buyers...

Comment: Or get a crossover, DACIA/Renault DUSTER Ford Ecosport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by your definition of comfort, I would suggest an SUV over a sedan. SUV's are more family oriented and are largely marketed either to women doing the school run, or guys doing off-road stuff. Both of those things require comfortable seating and driving dynamics.

Here's why:

- **Less noise.** SUV's have quieter exhausts as a general rule. They also have higher-profile tyres, which makes for quieter driving.
- **Ease of getting in and out of vehicle** SUV's don't require you to climb down into your seat. Some may be a bit high, but usually they allow you to "step in".
- **Easy to see all around the vehicle without much movement** The elevated seating position and big(ger) windows allow you to see everything very easily.
- **Seat provides good support for your back, or adjustable to individuals profile.** Largely dependent on the brand and model, but SUV's are aimed at people taking long trips, so the seats would be more comfortable.
- **Smoothness of the drive. Eg driving on the bumps on the road would be felt the least.** Taller tires and softer suspension in an SUV means more smoothness.

None of these things mean that other types of cars don't also provide high levels of comfort (or even higher levels of comfort), but SUV's are normally much more comfortable than equivalent sedans or hatchbacks. E.g. as always, let's take my Subaru Forester. It's built on the Impreza platform, and has the same engine and drivetrain, but it rides MUCH smoother. They're practically the same car, only difference is one is higher, has taller tires and has a slighlty softer suspension.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering buying a car and comfort is a requirement, look for cars which offer a height adjustable steering wheel, adjustable lumbar support in the seat and height adjustment on the seat.

Also, avoid the "sport" models as these are typically more firmly sprung so you will feel bumps in the road more severely.

Finally, test drive any prospective purchase as you won't get an indication of how comfortable they are for you personally unless you physically try them out.

As regards height of a car, I find that there is an optimum height.  Provided that you have enough headroom, they're comfortable.  For example, my old Porsche was a very low slung sports car but had sufficient height for me so was effectively comfortable.  The low height of the car also made it less susceptible to strong cross-winds so was less stressful than a high sided, high ride-height vehicle.